# vsts detailed notification after build or test fail

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to make vsts email me with a detailed transcript of why a test or build fails. At the moment all I am getting is te following email:
[image]

All this mail tells me that a test has failed but not what test or what the problem is. It does give me a link to open the build report in web access which has all the information about the type of error and even the stacktrace.

[image]

Is there a way to get this detailed information (error message and stack trace) into the email or can i make vsts send a custom email with this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are using VSTS default notification template (as a build fails template).

For now, there is no way to custom the notification template. And there has an user voice [Customise VSTS email templates](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/31353967-customise-vsts-email-templates) which suggest this feature. You can vote and follow up.

The workarounds for now as below:

- **Option 1:** Click the link "Open Build Report in Web Access" for detail build logs.
- **Option 2:** Add [Send Email task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rvo.SendEmailTask) at the end of your build definition, and select "Only when a previous task has failed" for run this task option, so that email will be sent if the build fails. And you can custom the email body as your need.

  [image]